# Invalid identifier in oracle query

Tags: oracle, plsql, case-when

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
FIRST_NAME AS "NAME",
CASE COUNTRY
    WHEN "FR" THEN "FRANCE"
    WHEN "USA" THEN "UNITED STATES"
    WHEN "C RO" THEN NULL
ELSE COUNTRY 
    END AS "COUNTRY"
FROM RAWDATA
```

It seems quite straigth forward but I get the following error:

```
ociexecute(): ORA-00904: "C RO": invalid identifier in path
```

I'm quite new to oracle so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  String literals in oracle are enclosed in single quotes. Double-quotes are used to enclose identifiers (like table and column names) , but not needed in your example.

```
SELECT 
FIRST_NAME AS NAME,
CASE COUNTRY
    WHEN 'FR' THEN 'FRANCE'
    WHEN 'USA' THEN 'UNITED STATES'
    WHEN 'C RO' THEN NULL
ELSE 'COUNTRY'
    END AS COUNTRY
FROM RAWDATA
```

Comment: I believe you need single quotes around the "COUNTRY" in "ELSE COUNTRY" as that is a string being returned.

Comment: NP, us old guys need to stick together.